# Is Primal Queen of Blades infested-human of primal zerg or a pure zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm wondering what is really the origin of the Primal Queen Of Blades

- Is an infested-human ?
- She's a Primal Zerg ?
- Pure Zerg ?

May anyone help me to answer?

Answer (score 1):

She is not infested. She has a perfect balance of Terran and Primal Zerg DNA, neither overpowering the other. That is why she still retains her human personality despite her Zerg form.